# Is any QMA-intermediate problem known?

Tags: quantum-computing, np-intermediate

Similar to the class of classical NP-intermediate problems (e.g. Graph Isomorphism), is there any "QMA-intermediate" problem known, that is in QMA but not known to be QMA-complete? Has this been studied systematically before?

Comment: And I suppose you want that the problem is not known to be in NP (or BQP, of course).

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Everything in QMA${}_1$, UniqueQMA, QCMA, etc. Pretty much any problem in any subclass of QMA. Perhaps you could be more specific about which subclasses of QMA you wish to exclude? (Such as BQP and NP.)

Comment: Indeed! I should have thought of these well known restrictions on QMA immediately! Somehow I was thinking more in terms of concrete problems, but of course you're right. You may want to put this as an answer.

Answer (score 9):

An example would be the computation of ground state energy of the Ising model with transverse magnetic fields, as described by [[Cubitt+Montenaro-2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3161)]. From the abstract:

> In this work we characterise the complexity of [the calculation of ground-state energies of 2-body Hamiltonians on qubits with terms restricted to some fixed set S]. Depending on the subset S, the problem falls into one of the following categories: in **P**; **NP**-complete; polynomial-time equivalent to the Ising model with transverse magnetic fields; or **QMA**-complete. The third of these classes contains **NP** and is contained within **StoqMA**.